# disk management/diskpart on windows server 2008 hangs

Tags: windows-server-2008, diskmanagement, diskpart

I am having an issue on my Windows Server 2008 "Sql Server".

When I access Disk Management, the UI hangs on "Loading disk configuration information"

When I run diskpart it does nothing after showing the server name.

I NEED to expand my secondary drive because I need to move my database files off the C drive (I have like 4 gb free space).

EDIT:
In the past, I used my domain controller to access disk management remotely to expand a drive and it worked on a different machine.  On this one, however, the disk management hands even on the DC.

Any ideas?

Comment: out of interest were you using mcafee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

- Run a **chkdsk /f** on all disks in the system to make sure they are ok.
- Open up **services.msc** and make sure the following services are started: **Remote Procedure Call (RPC)**, **Plug and Play** and **Virtual Disk**.

Comment: I don't know why, but it just worked one day when we were in crisis aversion mode. We never found out what was going on or why it suddenly worked.  Updates to the underlying linux, changes in settings, or maybe some vooodoo magic seemed to cure it.  Thanks for your suggestions Matthew.